# xamarin ios app doesn't list in installed apps in settings

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app, I've already released it for android and now it is iOS turn, but I have some platform specific problems, I'd like to debug them, but I can't, I found that I need to turn it on from settings, where all installed apps are in list, but I can't find my app there, but it's installed on my ipad! What's the problem? I have another Xamarin iOS app and it is there, in installed apps list, no problem with it, only with my Xamarin Forms app, any ideas?